# how to get caller arguments string in golang? is it impossible?

Tags: go, reflection, runtime

How can I return `user.Class.Name` string in reflectCallArgs. Is it impossible?

```
type User struct {
    Class struct {
        Name string
    }
}
var user = &User{}
reflectCallArgs := func(src interface{}) string {
    //how to get this string?
    return "user.Class.Name"
}
reflectCallArgs(user.Class.Name)
```

Answer (score 0):

The nearest thing you can get is the filename and line number where the function is being called, by querying `runtime.Caller`. https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Caller

```
func Caller(skip int) (pc uintptr, file string, line int, ok bool)
```

> Caller reports file and line number information about function invocations on the calling goroutine's stack. The argument skip is the number of stack frames to ascend, with 0 identifying the caller of Caller. (For historical reasons the meaning of skip differs between Caller and Callers.) The return values report the program counter, file name, and line number within the file of the corresponding call. The boolean ok is false if it was not possible to recover the information.

However, you need to have access to that file and be able to parse the file (or that single line) to get "caller arguments string".

Comment: how the get the single line in caller? or  so it is impossible to get the caller arguments string?

Comment: That piece of info is not build into the binary, so you cannot access it without the source file.